# Selenium Python: Switch window and find element

Tags: python, selenium

I am downloading an excel report from a URL. When I click excel download, a new window pops up with a 'in progress' message initially and followed by a 'completion' message.
I want to close Chrome session after completing the download.
I am using below code but somehow I am unable to locate element on new window. Kindly advise where am I wrong.
(PS: I can't share URL)

```
    #Excel Download
    link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[@alt='Export to Excel']")[0]
    link.click()
    driver.switch_to_window
    time.sleep (5)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"_NS__workingMsg")))
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[text()='Your report is ready and will download to your Web browser in a few moments.']")))
    time.sleep (2)
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you would need to switch the driver focus to new window :

```
current_handle = driver.window_handles
link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[@alt='Export to Excel']")[0]
link.click()
new_handle = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(new_handle[1])
```

and then you can perform action on new window.

**Update 1  :**

to close both of them you can do this :

```
driver.close()

driver.switch_to.window(new_handle[0])

driver.close()
```

or otherwisem, directly do this :

```
driver.quit()
```

quite will close all instance

Comment: driver.close()     closed only new popped up session however I want to close both (old and new)

Comment: so for that you would again have to switch to original handle. Check out the updated code.

Comment: the downloaded excel is also getting open automatically, how can I close that also?

Comment: Selenium can not close that. that's out of browser scope right ?

Comment: yes.. in a new excel session. but can we prevent the auto opening of excel.

Comment: hmm.. that's not an ideal behavior. Do you mind to create a new ticket with exact issue.